# XML and tree, line get out the tree

Tags: java, xml, tree, nodes

I want to transform my XML file into a tree in Java with the framework Vaadin. But with one line it get out the tree and I don't understand why, to understand I made a little one XML:

```
<overlay>
    <type>bgp</type>
    <bgp>
        <bgp-asn>12</bgp-asn>
    </bgp>
</overlay>
<overlay-routing>
    <type>test</type>
    <b>
        <bgp-as>11</bgp-as>
    </b>
</overlay-routing>
```

And here the result :
[image: tree]

So you can see I just change the name of my line in XML and it works, but with the "bgp-asn" it doesn't work and I really don't understand. It is a key work for XML ? Or something like that ?
I can put my code :

```
private Component test(){
        VerticalLayout ver = new VerticalLayout();
        ver.setSizeFull();
        TextArea text = new TextArea();
        Button send = new Button("send");
        tre = new Tree();
        tre.setSizeFull();

        send.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if(text.isEmpty()){
                    return;
                }
                Node node = getData(text.getValue());
                loadTree(tre, null, node);
            }
        });

private Document getData(String data){
        data = "<capsule>" + data;
        data = data + "</capsule>";
        try {
            if(data == null){
                return null;
            } else {
                try{
                    builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e){
                    throw new RuntimeException("cannot create a data source", e);
                }
                return builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.trim().getBytes("UTF-8")));
            }
            //return data == null ? null : builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.trim().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot load data from content", e);
        }
    }
```

and loadtree:

```
private void loadTree(Tree tree, Object parentID, Node element){

        if(tree == null || element == null){
            return;
        }
        final String itemID = (element.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE ? element.getNodeValue() : element.getNodeName()).trim();

        if(itemID.length() == 0){
            return;
        }
        tree.addItem(itemID);

        if(parentID != null){
            tree.setParent(itemID, parentID);
        }
        NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println(parentID);
        for(int i = 0, n = children.getLength(); i < n; i++){

            loadTree(tree, itemID, children.item(i));
        }
        if(children.getLength() > 0){
            tree.expandItem(itemID);
        } else{
            tree.setChildrenAllowed(itemID, false);
        }
    }
```

If you know what is wrong, it will be awesome ! 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know now, there was a problem with the value like bgp and the tag < bgp> my code did not make the difference. I have to add 2 lines to make it right. Here the good part for the function loadtree()

```
private void loadTree(Tree tree, Object parentID, Node element){

        if(tree == null || element == null){
            return;
        }

        final String itemID = (element.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE ? element.getNodeValue() : element.getNodeName()).trim();

        if (itemID.equals("#document")) {
            loadTree(tree, null, element.getChildNodes().item(0));
            return;
        }

        if(itemID.length() == 0){
            return;
        }
//add this two lines
        Object item = tree.addItem();
        tree.setItemCaption(item, itemID);

        if(parentID != null){
            tree.setParent(item, parentID);
        }

        NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
        for(int i = 0, n = children.getLength(); i < n; i++){

            loadTree(tree, item, children.item(i));
        }

        if(itemID.equals("root")){
            tree.expandItem(item);
        }

        if(children.getLength() == 0){
            tree.setChildrenAllowed(item, false);
        }
    }
```

And now it is perfect !
Thank you.